# Understanding Characteristics in Bluetooth Low Energy for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to simply read and Write Hello World from an galaxy S3 to a blueradio dongle which is connected to a virtual serial port.  but I am getting

```
Unhandled exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when ever i call

```
gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

I use this to define the characteristic

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private static final UUID charUUID = UUID.fromString("00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
characteristic = gatt.getService(MY_UUID).getCharacteristic(charUUID);
```

The UUID I took from the LogCat when i called discoverServices() as so

```
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): discoverServices() - device: EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetService() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetService() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetService() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetService() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=da2b84f1-6279-48de-bdc0-afbea0226079
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetCharacteristic() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetCharacteristic() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetCharacteristic() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt(7083): onGetCharacteristic() - Device=EC:FE:7E:11:12:A4 UUID=00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

This is where Im not sure if I am doing i correctly I dont know how to get the proper UUID for a characteristic and service

Beloiw is my full Callback function

```
private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    public void testFunction(BluetoothGatt gatt){
        Log.d(TAG, "In Test Function");
        gatt.readRemoteRssi();
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        characteristic = gatt.getService(MY_UUID).getCharacteristic(charUUID);
        characteristic.setValue("Hello World");
        gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
     @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
            int newState) {


            gatt.discoverServices();


    }


@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Services Discovered: "+ status);
    //mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Sensors..."));
    /*
     * With services discovered, we are going to reset our state machine and start
     * working through the sensors we need to enable
     */
            testFunction(gatt);
}


public void     onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
    Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic Changed: "+ characteristic.getValue());
}

public void     onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic Read: "+ status);
}

public void     onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic Write: "+ status);
}



public void     onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor Read: "+ status);
}

public void     onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor Write: "+ status);
}

public void     onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Read Rssi: "+ status);
}

public void     onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){
    Log.d(TAG, "Reliable Write: "+ status);
}


};
```

Comment: You should probably start by figuring out precisely what is null, and then why.  If your post is literally correct about the line on which the exception occurs, then your "gatt" object is null there, however it seems as likely that is not the precise line of the exception.

Comment: Ive tried everything else with gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic); commented out and I do not get that error so its either my characteristic or gatt that is null

Comment: You can figure out *which* by logging (or the debugger) and from there proceed to figure out *why*.  Though technically, if that is the exact line specified for the occurrence of exception (and not just part of its call stack) then only gatt could be the null.

Answer (score 5):

UUID is predefined by bluetooth.org, it defines the prefix, e.g. 00001800, the last part "0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" are same for all.

see the list of predefined UUID [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/).

Comment: link is dead, do you mean https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to to the same thing with the Blueradio USB dongle.
I found the following info on BlueRadio Android example project. May be this info might be useful to you

**UUID for BRSP SERVICE**

```
DA2B84F1627948DEBDC0AFBEA0226079
```

**Characteristic UUID for BRSP**

```
99564A02DC014D3CB04E3BB1EF0571B2  --> Info

A87988B9694C479C900E95DFA6C00A24  --> Mode

BF03260C72054C25AF4393B1C299D159  --> RX

18CDA7844BD3437085BBBFED91EC86AF  --> TX(Data sent to Client PC/ANDROID from BLE)

0A1934F524B84F13984237BB167C6AFF  --> CTS

FDD6B4D3046D4330BDEC1FD0C90CB43B --> RTS
```

If you find out more info please share.

Thanks
John